# how to using scrollbar to dynamic allocation button in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i make web page using html, javascript, jquery.
i want to use a horizontal scroll bar for tabbar.
I'll put a dynamic allocation button in tabbar.
When many buttons are created, the buttons are created in the underline so i can not using scroll.

i want create button on the horizontal scroll view in the line. and i will using scrollLeft method to arrow button.

What is the problem?

1. display style change to inline-block.
2. overflow-x: auto -> scroll.
   but it was not fixed.

after i using flex block. but it didn't work out the way I wanted it to.
I don't want to use a part of the flex layout.

```
<script>
// .js
function push_btn(){
    var addedTabDiv = document.getElementById("scroll_view_tabbar");
    var tab_code = "";
    tab_code += "<input type='button' id='tab_btn' class='tab_btn' value='tab_btn' />";
    tab_code += "<input type='button' id='tab_btn_x' class='tab_btn_x' value='X' />";
    var addedTab = document.createElement("div");
    addedTab.id = "scroll_view_btn_div";
    addedTab.className = "scroll_view_btn_div";
    addedTab.innerHTML  = tab_code;
    addedTabDiv.appendChild(addedTab);
}
</script>

<style>
/* .css */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}

.scroll_view_tabbar{
    width:800px;
    height:30px;
    dlsplay:inline-block;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll; /* or auto; */
}
.scroll_view_btn_div{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    dlsplay:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.tab_btn{
    width:70px;
    height:30px;
    dlsplay:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.tab_btn_x{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    dlsplay:inline-block;
    float:right;
}


.tabbar_arrow_left{
    width : 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display:none;
    float : left;
}

.tabbar_arrow_right{
    width : 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display:none;
    float : right;
}
</style>

<!-- html -->
<button onclick="push_btn()">Add</button>
<div id="scroll_view_tabbar" class="scroll_view_tabbar"></div>
```

if use push_btn() and many buttons are created, the buttons are created in the underline.

Comment: Please make clear what you're trying to achieve and what the problem is with illustrations (you can embed screenshots). It's hard to understand your question.

Comment: I've edited your code sample so that it can be run in a browser. But it would be helpful if you added the code for tabbar_arrow functionality. It's not clear what you mean by "buttons are created in the underline"?

Comment: so sorry. and answer this question.      I want to use "white-space:nowrap".    -> "white-space:nowrap" is blocked  "float:left"

Answer (score 0):

I want to use "white-space:nowrap".
It did not apply. So created button is position in under.
I found it.

"white-space:nowrap" is blocked "float:left"

Thank you for your interest. sorry.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrfAl.png)
want it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFWBT.png)
blocked "white-space:nowrap". It was my problem.